# Problemas con Autologin en una web usando curl con PHP

Tags: php, curl

estoy intentando hacer un autologin desde php a un sitio web pero me está dando más dolores de cabeza de lo que pensaba. Tengo la siguiente función:

```
public function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
    define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
    //We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    return curl_exec ($login);
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}
```

El curl no da ningún error y se ejecuta pero el problema es que el login no se hace. Tengo otra función para abrir una página y cualquier página que ponga funciona, en cambio si intento poner la url de la página a la que estoy intentando acceder oculta sin login lo que hace es llevarme al login porque la función login no hace su cometido.

No soy un experto en el tema, pero si puedo asegurar que tanto los parámetros como la url están correctas en la llamada a la función (la llamo dentro de una clase):

$this->login("https:/misitio/login.php","usuario=".$username."&contrasenna=".$password."");

A ver si alguien me puede dar alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En ese curl estás enviando una petición con método POST y en $data deberían ir las credenciales, además en su formato correcto, (http_build_query). Si metes las credenciales en $url se estarán enviando con método GET que probablemente la url ignorará.

Para saber de qué se queja podrías poner esto:

```
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_STDERR, 'curldebug.txt');
```

y ver en el curldebug.txt qué está pasando en esa conexión.

Answer (score 1):

Muchísimas gracias por responder.

Por un lado he modificado la función por tema de los valores se pasen como una http_build_query de este modo

public function login($url,$username,$password){

```
$postValues = array(
'usuario' => $username,
'contrasenna' => $password
);


$fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$login = curl_init();
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
//We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$curl_log = fopen("curldebug.txt", 'w');
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);

return curl_exec ($login);
//curl_close ($login);
unset($login);
```

}

No ha resultado favorable en el intento del login, y por otro lado no me escribe nada en el txt del debug, no se si porque no tiene nada que escribir o porque he hecho algo mal.

Comment: Gracias, me salvaste